# Degrees of Freedom of a Linear Triatomic Molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

I was introduced to a formula for finding the DOF of a molecule which was
$3N-k$ and I was told, it was just for translation and rotational degree of freedom. Here $N$ is the no. of atoms in that molecule, and $k$ is the no. of independent criteria (like bonds). For example, if it's a diatomic molecule, then $DOF=3(2)-1$ which is 5. But by this, when I find for Triatomic Linear molecule $DOF=3(3)-2$ which is 7. And visualising the molecule I could find only 5 DOF.
So I raised up the question, but I didn't find a satisfactory response.
If there are any considerations or something that's missing, please help.

Comment: Refer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426330/2-extra-degree-of-freedom-in-linear-triatomic-molecules#)

Comment: There must be some undisclosed assumptions underlying your formula. I prefer the explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry)#Counting_the_Minimum_Number_of_Coordinates_to_Specify_a_Position]

Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry)#Counting_the_Minimum_Number_of_Coordinates_to_Specify_a_Position

Cleary you can see all linear molecules at moderate temperature has 5 DOF

Answer (score -1):

Everything is right, IN Triatomic  linear molecule (like:co2) has two vibration mode in normal room temperature.
So,
F=3+2+2=7,
But many books not explain it well manner,
That is why you get  Cv value =7/2RT.
(Mind: linear triatomic molecules has 4 vibrational mode (v=3(3)-5=4),but we attained two modes of vibration normal room temperature,so total freedom is 7)