# 2 Extra Degree of Freedom in Linear Triatomic Molecules?

Tags: kinetic-theory, vibrations, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

Ok, there is a bit problem in understanding **Degree of Freedom of Linear Molecules** specially of *Triatomic Linear Molecules*.

See, the DOF in general is given as $f=3N-k$.
Here,
*N*=Number of atoms in a molecule
*k*=Total number of constraints

If there are **no constraints**, then DOF generally is, $f=3N$

Coming to Linear Molecules, let's first assume that the molecules are at *low temperatures* such that the constituent atoms are **not vibrating**.

Now, as per [this wikipedia link of DOF(Physics and Chemistry) under Gas Molcules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry)), it generalizes the degree of freedom of linear molecules.

With no vibrational modes to consider, it says that:-

DOF of linear molecules: $5$ and is **independent to the atomicity of the molecule**

[image]

*Reason*:-

$3$ Translational DOF + $2$ Rotational DOF + $0$ Vibrational DOF = $5$ DOF

**Note**: Translation and Rotation about it's Cente of Mass.

Pretty Logical for any type of linear molecules(Di-,Triatomic,etc.)

Similar generalization is also done for *Non-Linear Molecules*. But we'll keep our focus on Linear Molecules for now.

Now, let's use the formula stated at the beginning. As the formula clearly has the *atomicity factor N*, we'll consider a basic triatomic linear molecule (also, because this specific molecule is creating doubts).

As the 3 atoms aren't vibrating(assumed initially), so there are 2 fixed distances between the 3 atoms on a straight line.
Hence,

$k=2 ;N=3$
$f=3N-k=7=5+2$

Now, the doubt can be clearly seen.

The 5 degree of freedom of the molecule is explained earlier.
So, if *vibrational modes are neglected* for now, then what are those **2 extra DOFs** for linear triatomic molecules signifies?

If 5 DOF of linear molecules(given in the wiki) is the actual answer, then, can we say that $f=3N-k$ which I think a general equation is *not so general and reliable equation to evaluate DOF of molecules*?

---

Pretty similar question is asked [here in this community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378109/degrees-of-freedom-of-a-linear-triatomic-molecule).
But, there's nothing in response to that post, so I thought to give it a second go.

Another question which give some insight to me is [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193249/extra-vibrational-mode-in-linear-molecule).
But it didn't answer the 2 questions given above precisely.

---

### EDIT

Recently, I noticed that the *specific ratio,* $\gamma$ of CO<sub>2</sub>(a trilinear molecule) is $1.30$.

Pretty close to $1.28$ which happens to be the $\gamma$ of trilinear molecules at **low temperatures** where any kind of vibrational degree of freedom is not present.

Now, for solving $\gamma$, first $C_p$ and $C_v$ are evaluated using *dof* of trilinear molecule which is taken $7$.

So, the discussion in this post earlier concluded that in those 7 dofs, 2 dofs are basically **degenerate cases of bending** in which the extreme atoms of the molecule remain at a constant distance from the *vibrating* middle atom.

But *as bending is more like a vibrational dof, then it can't exist at low temperatures*.

And so,

At this point, excluding the bending nature of atoms and evaluating $\gamma$ of *trilinear molecules* using $f=5$ seems more appropriate.

But assuming $f=5$ means rejecting the standard value of $\gamma=1.30$ of CO<sub>2</sub>.

So, the question here is that if those 2 extra dofs are really vibrational dofs(to be precise, degenerate cases of bending) then why these 2 are considered to evaluate $\gamma$ of CO<sub>2</sub>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trilinear molecule can bend in the middle. In two directions.
These are your extra two degrees of freedom.

Comment: Does bending in between changes the bond length? Because if it does, then the distance between the  atoms changes and how can I count changing distance as a constraint???

Comment: No.  The lengths are the same but the angle changes from 180 degrees to 179 degrees (or whatever)

Comment: @RojerJBarlow Ok, so, the 2 extra vibrational dofs are due to bending. But those 2 dofs are similar in vibration but *different in directions*. One is *along the plane* and another is *in and out of plane*. So, considering [my previous post of thermal and dynamic DOF](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418968/actual-degree-of-freedom-of-diatomic-molecule), these 2 dofs can be considered as 2 *different dynamic dofs* but also 2 *same thermal dofs*. Because no matter in which direction, the atoms are bending, they are storing the energy in same way. Am I right??

Comment: For a triatomic molecule these two degrees of freedom are degenerate, yes, as bending in the xy plane is the same as bending in the xz plane (with the molecule along the x axis), or any combination of the two.  Their energy is more like vibrational modes than rotational/translational so they will not get excited at low temperatures.

Comment: @RojerJBarlow you might need to take a look on my edited post.

Comment: So if we allow vibrations to occur, how many degrees if freedom will the molecule have?