# Is the equation for degrees of freedom $f=3N-k$ valid for all cases?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, gas, degrees-of-freedom

Consider the example of a linear triatomic molecule. Now at low temperatures, where we can exclude vibration, quite clearly degrees of freedom, $f=5$, with 3 translational and 2 rotational degrees of freedom. But if we calculate it using, $f=3N-k$, we get $k=2$, and hence $f=7$. How do we explain this?

Also, in addition if we consider the distance of the end atoms to be fixed with respect to each other, (which I think we should, to avoid counting vibration modes) we get k=3 and hence f=6, and still not f=5. Is there a constraint that I'm missing? Please explain.

Comment: How do you define $k$?

Comment: Look at this Q&A: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378109/degrees-of-freedom-of-a-linear-triatomic-molecule?rq=1

Comment: k is the number of holonomic constraints.

Comment: I've checked that question, didn't really have the answer to my question. Could you please look into it and answer here?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you are getting your numbers from. There are $3$ degrees of freedom that represent a translation of the molecule as a whole. There are $2$ rotational degree of freedom for a linear molecule and $3$ rotational degree of freedom for a non-linear molecule - the constraint that tends to keep the atoms of a linear molecule in line with one another removes a rotational degree of freedom. The *maximum* number of remaining degrees of freedom (vibrational or normal modes) for a molecule with $N$ atoms is $3N-5$ for a linear molecule and $3N-6$ for a non-linear molecule. However, additional constraints may remove some of these vibrational degrees of freedom.

So a linear three atom molecule has at most $9$ degrees of freedom - $3$ translational, $2$ rotational and $4$ vibrational. However, if you fix the distance between the two outermost atoms, you introduce an additional constraint, which removes one degree of freedom - the vibrational mode in which the outermost atoms vibrate 180 degrees out of phase with each other is no longer possible. This leaves $3$ vibrational degree of freedom. The total number of degrees of freedom is now $3$ translational, $2$ rotational and $3$ vibrational, giving a total of $8$.

If you remove *all* the vibrational degrees of freedom, you are left with just the $3$ translational degrees of freedom and either $2$ (for a linear molecule) or $3$ (for a non-linear molecule) rotational degrees of freedom.

See [this paper](https://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/notes/NormalModesText.pdf) for a detailed explanation of the normal modes of a linear three atom molecule.

Comment: You're saying that the expression f=3N-k isn't valid everywhere? Also, aren't 2 degrees of freedom associated with each vibrational mode? So shouldn't there be 13 degrees of freedom for the linear triatomic molecule? I'm very confused.

Comment: So far I've been using f=3N-k, and it seems to be working well everytime except in this case. For eg. Consider a non-linear triatomic molecule. N=3,  holonomic constraints, k=3, and hence, f=3, ( 3 Rotational and 3 Translational degrees of freedom).

Comment: @SrijanDas For the linear triatomic molecule with no vibrational modes, you have two constraints due to fixed bond lengths and a further two constraints due to keeping the bonds aligned, hence there are $4$ constraints, so $k$ is $4$ and you are left with $3 \times 3 - 4 = 5$ degrees of freedom. But it is far simpler to just add translational and rotational degrees of freedom to get $3+2=5$.

Comment: @SrijanDas Also, I think you may be confusing the number of energy terms and the number of degrees of freedom. There are $2$ energy terms associated with each vibrational mode, not $2$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Doesn't keeping the distance constant between the two end atoms take care of keeping the bonds aligned? Hence I got k=3 and not 4. Could you please explain this?

Comment: Also, could you please tell me whether the degrees of freedom for a diatomic molecule at a high temperature is 6 or 7? Because I've read that the degree of freedom corresponds to the number of quadratic terms in the Hamiltonian of the system, hence, two degrees of freedom per vibrational mode. By that logic, f=7 for diatomic molecules and 13 for linear triatomic molecules.

Comment: @SrijanDas Note that the terminology is inconsistent, and you have to be careful. *I* use "degrees of freedom" to mean a quadratic energy term, but other people (e.g., this poster) use it in other ways, like a vibrational dof = two quadratic energy terms (I would call this a vibrational *mode*). Forget the *names* for a moment. What matters thermodynamically is how many *quadratic energy terms* there are in the Hamiltonian. That's what we're actually counting.

Answer (score 1):

I have realized that a clear explanation about this point seems to be missing.

The possible confusion about the number of holonomic constraints is probably due to the singular behavior of the angular coordinates. However, there is a simple way to understand how the correct counting of $5$ degrees of freedom comes from in the case of a linear, rigid tri-atomic molecule.

Without constraints, the positions of three atoms in the space require $9$ coordinates.
In the case of a linear, rigid molecule, fixing the position of the first atom corresponds to the first three degrees of freedom. Fixing the position of a second atom at a given distance from the first requires only two angular coordinates. If the third atom has a fixed distance from the second and is aligned with the first two, no freedom is left.

Said in another way, the rigidity of two bond lengths would reduce the number of degrees of freedom from $9$ to $7$. The angular orientation of the second atom with respect to the first requires other two degrees of freedom. The orientation of the third with respect to the second would require the two additional degrees of freedom to sum $7$. Still, the constraint of linearity means that we have two other constraints on the two angles of the third atom relative to the direction of the first two.

Comment: Is there anyway to obtain this from the f=3N-k expression? For eg. let the 3 atoms be - A,B and C, with C being the middle atom. The constraints are - 1) The distance AB is fixed, 2) BC is fixed and 3)AC is fixed. These 3 holonomic constraints should cover the rotational and vibrational degrees of freedom right? Then we obtain f=6. Am I missing out on something or is the expression not always applicable?

Comment: Maybe It is useful to note that your conditions 1, 2 and 3 generally fix the molecole on a specific triangle, for which f=6. You obtain a linear configuration in the limiting case d(A,C)=d(A,B)+d(B,C) which you may think like constraining the third molecole to a circle of zero radius, hence giving a further constraint...